# Are there homomorphisms of group algebras that don't come from a group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-rings

Given a ***finite*** group $G$, one can define the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as the algebra having the elements of $G$ as a basis, with the multiplication of $G$. Clearly, any group homomorphism induces an algebra homomorphism on the group algebras.

I'm wondering whether one can prove that any algebra homomorphism of two group algebras must always come from a homomorphism of groups.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2372732?uid=378469401&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21103832682693 would help.

Comment: That's got to do with compact Lie groups, is it applicable to finite groups?

Comment: I don't think it should be difficult to give an example of an algebra homomorphism that doesn't come from a group homomorphism.

Comment: @Dustan, That's what I suspected, but I'm trying since half an hour. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong groups...

Comment: For instance, there's only one automorphism of $G = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (the trivial one), but $\mathbb C[G] \simeq \mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C$ has at least one nontrivial automorphism, given by interchanging the summands.

Comment: How is sending 1 to anything else than 1 an automorphism?

Comment: The isomorphism $\mathbb C[G] \simeq \mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C$ is actually true as rings, which I take it you're not familiar with.

Comment: @Dustan, it seems I'm not familiar enough. How does the isomorphism you mean look like?

Comment: I worked it out the hard way and then it turns out it's pretty obvious... I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G = \{e, \sigma\}$ be the group of order $2$. Then $\{e, \sigma\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb C[G]$. The linear map given by $e \mapsto e$ and $\sigma \mapsto -\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb C[G]$ that does not come from a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the dihedral group of order $8$ and the quaternions have isomorphic group algebras.  Taking an isomorphism  and restricting it to the basis of the dihedral group given by the elements of the group does not give you the basis of the quaternions given by the elements of the group because if it did this would imply that the dihedral group and the quaternions were isomorphic as groups.  So in this sense it does not "come from a group homomorphism".

Comment: That sounds interesting! You say "it is well known", but when I search for dihedral group, group algebra and quaternions, I can't find anything about this algebra isomorphism.

Comment: @Turion in general, if the set of irreducible representations have the same dimensions, then the group algebras are isomorphic. This is related to the remark I was making above, and is not a trivial result.

Comment: Right, so I could have also just used any two nonisomorphic abelian groups of the same order, for example.  Also it should be intuitive that "most" algebra homomorphisms between group algebras are not induced by group homomorphisms.

Comment: Ah, so already $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_4] \cong \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z}_2]$? I wonder whether these kind of isomorphisms are also equivalences of representation categories.

Comment: Yes, for complex group algebras over finite groups their irreducible representations are the same iff the group algebras are isomorphic.  This result takes some representation theory and structure theorems to prove.

Comment: Finally found a reference online that would at least write out the claim explicitly. Page 37/38 of [these lecture notes](http://staffweb.itsligo.ie/staff/lcreedon/Research/LeosMastersKGnotes.pdf), Corollary 4.9, is what we've been referring to, with $K = \mathbb C$ and $n_i$ the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $G$. I'm sure there's a better reference somewhere, but it was amazingly difficult to find something that even stated the result in one go (rather than indirectly by saying it's semisimple and requiring a bit more reading to understand the implications of that).